# AngularJS won't update view but $scope does

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Ionic Framework to build my app. I have a item list `(productos.html)`. Each of them is a `<a>` tag with `href` to detail `(producto.html)`. I can sell my product there with `registrarVenta` method. His callback calls `listarProductos` method, that retrieve the updated products list (the sold product is not there). That method transitions to `app.productos` state, where I have to show the $scope.productos list. The `$scope.productos` is updated, but the `ng-repeat` for productos is not! I cant use `$scope.$apply()` function. Any ideas?

**PS:** Excuse me for my english, my native languge

**app.js**

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'starter.controllers', 
    'starter.services', 'starter.filters', 'starter.factories'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/menu.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.productos', {
        url: '/productos',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'views/productos.html',
                controller: 'ProductosController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.producto', {
        url: '/productos/:idProducto',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'views/producto.html',
                controller: 'ProductosController'
            }
        }
    })

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/productos');
});
```

**controllers.js**

```js
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
    .controller('ProductosController', function($scope, $q, $http, $state, $stateParams) {
        $scope.idProductoSeleccionado = $stateParams.idProducto;
        $scope.busqueda;
        $scope.venta = {
            cliente: 1,
            variante: $scope.idProductoSeleccionado,
            entrega: null
        };
        $scope.productos = null;

        $scope.listarProductos = function(){
            $scope.productos = null;
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http.get(url + 'productos')
            .then(function(response){
                $scope.productos = response.data.productos;
                console.log('productos callback', $scope.productos); //it works every time but wont update view
                defer.resolve(true);
            }, function(error){
                $scope.productos = null;
                console.log(error);
                defer.reject(error);
            });
            return defer.promise;
        };
        $scope.listarProductos();

        $scope.registrarVenta = function(){
            $scope.productos = null;
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http.post(url + 'registrar-venta', $scope.venta)
            .then(function(response){
                console.log('productos before', $scope.productos);  //non-updated list => OK
                $scope.listarProductos();
                console.log('productos after', $scope.productos);  //null => OK

                $scope.venta = null;
                $state.go('app.productos');

                defer.resolve(response.data.message);
            }, function(error){
                if(window.plugins && window.plugins.toast) {
                    window.plugins.toast.showLongCenter(error);
                } else {
                    console.error(error);
                }
                defer.reject(error);
            });
            return defer.promise;
        };
    })
```

**productos.html**

```html
<ion-view view-title="Productos">
<ion-content>
<div class="content padding">
    <h1 class="title">Productos</h1>
    <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input ng-disabled="!productos" type="text" placeholder="Buscar productos" ng-model="busqueda" >
        </label>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="!productos" class="loading"><ion-spinner icon="dots"></ion-spinner> <span>Cargando productos...<span></div>

    <ul class="list">
        <!--  | searchFor:busqueda -->
        <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="producto in productos | searchForProducto:busqueda " href="#/app/productos/{{producto.idVariante}}">
            <img src="{{producto.foto}}">
            <h2>{{producto.nombre}}</h2>
            <p><strong>Talles:</strong> {{producto.talles}}</p>
            <p><strong>Colores:</strong> {{producto.colores}}</p>
            <span class="badge badge-assertive badge-normal">$ {{producto.precioVenta}}</span>
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: I think this is a digest issue try wrapping it in the $timeout service

Comment: I tried append $timeout function, but the problems persists...

Comment: as soon as you change state you lose the scope of the controller and create new instance of controller. That new instance has no knowledge of the previous one

Comment: Great tip! So, how should I save it? Should I use a service to store my list?

Comment: Rootscope might be easier

Comment: Save models in rootScope instead of scope? I'll try. It could works.